# How to break pandas dataframe break where row contains </s> </s> in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a pandas dataframe file.I'm trying to break up a dataframe column contains `</s> </s>`.

```
column A                            column B  
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'abc')            0.043025210084033615
(('<s>', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.65234375
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.04259501965923984
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.18604651162790697
(('abc', 'abc'),  '</s>')           0.41317365269461076
(('abc', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.011148272017837236
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'def')            0.09090909090909091
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.008287292817679558
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.13506493506493505
(('def', 'def'),  '</s>')           0.007653061224489796
(('def', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.08333333333333333
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'ghi')            0.5
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.125
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.033766233766233764
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  '</s>')           0.0694980694980695
(('ghi','</s>'),  '</s>')           0.16666666666666666
```

I need to get output the below way. How can this be implemented in python or Regex? I am new to Python.

```
column A                            column B  
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'abc')            0.043025210084033615
(('<s>', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.65234375
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.04259501965923984
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.18604651162790697
(('abc', 'abc'),  '</s>')           0.41317365269461076
(('abc', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.011148272017837236

column A                            column B   
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'def')            0.09090909090909091
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.008287292817679558
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.13506493506493505
(('def', 'def'),  '</s>')           0.007653061224489796
(('def', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.08333333333333333

column A                            column B  
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'ghi')            0.5
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.125
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.033766233766233764
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  '</s>')           0.0694980694980695
(('ghi','</s>'),  '</s>')           0.16666666666666666
```

Comment: The values in each column are tuples? If you simply create a new column with the flattened concatenated string of column A, just run through the rows using `df.iterrows()` and have a few boolean flags for `seen_opentag` and `seen_closetag` and break by index (returned by `iterrows()`).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Allan: Markdown remote link references don't work in comments - you need to use inline references instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of what is possible:

**code:**

```
$ more replace.py 
import re

input = """column A                            column B  
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'abc')            0.043025210084033615
(('<s>', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.65234375
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.04259501965923984
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.18604651162790697
(('abc', 'abc'),  '</s>')           0.41317365269461076
(('abc', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.011148272017837236
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'def')            0.09090909090909091
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.008287292817679558
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.13506493506493505
(('def', 'def'),  '</s>')           0.007653061224489796
(('def', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.08333333333333333
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'ghi')            0.5
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.125
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.033766233766233764
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  '</s>')           0.0694980694980695
(('ghi','</s>'),  '</s>')           0.16666666666666666"""

print re.sub(r"(\(\('[^']*', '</s>'\), '</s>'\)\s+[0-9\.]+\s+)","\1\ncolumn A                            column B\n", input)
```

**output:**

```
$ python replace.py 
column A                            column B  
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'abc')            0.043025210084033615
(('<s>', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.65234375
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.04259501965923984
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.18604651162790697
(('abc', 'abc'),  '</s>')           0.41317365269461076

column A                            column B
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'def')            0.09090909090909091
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.008287292817679558
(('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.13506493506493505
(('def', 'def'),  '</s>')           0.007653061224489796

column A                            column B
(('<s>', '<s>'),  'ghi')            0.5
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.125
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.033766233766233764
(('ghi', 'ghi'),  '</s>')           0.0694980694980695
(('ghi','</s>'),  '</s>')           0.16666666666666666
```

**Explanations:**

- [demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/SjmJ7b/2/)
- for information about regex: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html
- code explanation: you replace each line that does match with the regex by exactly what the line contains (using backreference) and you append a new line with the 2 columns titles (check https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: My data looks  is  in the format of pandas (pd.dataframe )
how can i do that?